# ASP MVC 3 Getting XML results from search engine

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc-3

In my ASP.NET MVC 3 application, I am trying to use an external search engine.

The search engine is used as following :

I execute a URL with the search parameters I want like this

```
http://<Domain>/engine/ContactssCore/select?q=QUERY
```

This will return an XML result, which I am going to parse into C# objects.

My question is, how can I call this URL and get the XML result from my controller ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XDocument can load direcly from an external source

```
var xml = XDocument.Load("http://<Domain>/engine/ContactssCore/select?q=QUERY");
```

You should probably encode your QUERY parameter before making the request.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WebClient.DownloadString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstring%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method to get this done.